# In R, use lubridate to convert hms objects into seconds

Tags: r, lubridate

simple question in lubridate--I want to convert an hms object into its appropriate number of seconds since the start of the day.

For instance

```
library(lubridate)
hms("12:34:45")
```

then I want to know exactly how long 12 hours, 34 minutes, and 45 seconds is, in seconds

something obvious like

```
seconds(hms("12:34:45"))
```

just returns

```
45s
```

which is not what I want. How do I convert these hms values into seconds? I'd like to use lubridate

Comment: `as.duration()` perhaps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't matter which package you use -- it will have convert a date / datetime object  into a POSIXct representation of seconds since the epoch.  So you may as well do it in base R -- so here deploy `ISOdatetime()` with an arbitrary day, using today:

```
R> difftime(ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,12,34,45), ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,0,0,0))
Time difference of 12.5792 hours
```

So we want seconds:

```
R> difftime(ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,12,34,45), ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,0,0,0), 
+          unit="secs")
Time difference of 45285 secs
```

And we can cast to numbers:

```
R> as.numeric(difftime(ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,12,34,45), +
                       ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,0,0,0), unit="secs"))
[1] 45285
```

*Edit:*  And getting back to lubridate, this is arguably a bug:

```
> hms("12:34:45") - hms("00:00:00")
[1] 12 hours, 34 minutes and 45 seconds
R> as.numeric(hms("12:34:45") - hms("00:00:00"))
[1] 45
R>
```

Comment: Yeah, this will be more accurate than just `as.duration` which (I think) simply converts each piece to the "default" number of seconds. In lubridate you'd have to convert it to an interval first, which is basically what you're doing here, I guess.

Comment: lubridate does not invent new time types either so your suggested as.duration() may well work, or maybe a difference to hms("00:00:00"), or ...

Comment: Late to the party but thought I'd throw in: `out <- as.POSIXct("12:34:45", format="%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC"); difftime(out,trunc(out,"day"),units="secs")`

Comment: `as.numeric(as.POSIXct(paste("1970-01-01", "12:34:45")))`

Answer (score 37):

```
R>lubridate::period_to_seconds(hms("01:00:00"))
```

gives expected 3600 seconds as numeric counting from 00:00:00 
or in the case above:

```
R>period_to_seconds(hms("12:34:45"))
```